# When a star undergo collapse in a binary system what effect it has on its companion star?

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-physics, stellar-evolution, binary-stars, gravitational-collapse

when a star in its lifetime fuses up all its hydrogen and then collapse under gravitational force, till the temperature inside become high enough to restart the fusion of helium and radiation pressure becomes equivalent to gravitational force, stopping the collapse.

stars can be in a binary system of non-comparable masses. Here star with higher mass may evolve faster with time. So, in one of the stages of life such star, during collapse what effect it has on the companion star?

Comment: What you're describing is not really a "collapse" in the sense that the word is usually used (i.e. a star forming a white dwarf, neutron star, or black hole at the end of its life). You're describing an event that happens after the end of the Main Sequence lifetime of a low-mass star during the red-giant phase, which is usually referred to as the "helium flash."

Comment: Might be a better fit for Astronomy SE.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. There are any number of scenarios that can occur in binary evolution.

Comment: thanks for the comments,@probably someone, a star will go a collapse forming a helium flash or collapse forming a white dwarf are actually same right depending on the mass of the star.here, i meant does gravitational force which is  cause of this, has any effect on other star.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know much about neutron stars and specifically about the interaction of neutron stars with other neutron stars or celestial bodies, infact there is a whole problem in Physics related to this topic called the Mass Gap Problem, so any answer here is just a speculation based on our current understanding of Physics, which is quite limited when it comes to exotic things like Neutron Stars, black holes etc.
The short answer is, we don't really know what would happen, we can speculate but that's about it.

I assume, nothing would happen, the two would continue to orbit each other just as they did before, just as if our sun turned into a black hole, all the planets would still continue to orbit it just like they do now.

But if they had an unstable orbit, I would assume the two would catastopically collapse ending up with a larger neutron star or maybe a black hole. This is where the mass gap problem arises where we don't know if there is something inbetween a black hole and a neutron star.

Comment: Question has no obvious connection to neutron stars at all.